# What package should I use for laptop-mode on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, power-management

I've been puzzled, Ubuntu repository has two conflicted packages, `laptop-mode-tools` and `ubuntu-laptop-mode`. I can't find any information about differences in those packages, which one is better and even which one is recommended. Which one should I install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this clarification [from the author of laptop-mode-tools](http://samwel.tk/laptop_mode/faq):

> **What is the relationship between the
>   Ubuntu package "laptop-mode" and the
>   Debian package "laptop-mode-tools"?**
>
> There is a big thread about this on
>   ubuntuforums,
>   http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=36976.
>   Ubuntu used to have a rather outdated
>   package for controlling laptop mode,
>   based on the aforementioned kernel
>   documentation script. Laptop mode
>   tools basically is a much more recent
>   version of the same code. Ubuntu has
>   switched to laptop-mode-tools
>   somewhere in 2006.

I'm running Ubuntu 9.04, and **laptop-mode-tools** is installed by default on my system, not **ubuntu-laptop-mode**.

Answer (score 2):

`aptitude show ubuntu-laptop-mode`

> ... Support for reducing hard drive power
>   consumption  Laptop mode is a Linux
>   kernel feature that allows the system
>   to reduce power consumption by
>   allowing the hard drive  to spin down
>   for longer periods of time. This
>   package contains a script to control
>   these kernel parameters.

`aptitude show laptop-mode-tools`

> Scripts to spin down hard drive and
>   save power  Laptop mode is a Linux
>   kernel feature that allows your laptop
>   to save considerable power, by
>   allowing the hard  drive to spin down
>   for longer periods of time. This
>   package contains the userland scripts
>   that are needed to enable  laptop
>   mode. It includes support for
>   automatically enabling laptop mode
>   when the computer is working on
>   batteries.  It also supports various
>   other power management features, such
>   as starting and stopping daemons
>   depending on power  mode,
>   automatically hibernating if battery
>   levels are too low, and adjusting
>   terminal blanking and X11 screen 
>   blanking.

So it definitely looks like laptop-mode-tools has more features and might do your laptop more good.

Answer (score 0):

Laptop-mode-tools. If I remember correctly it has support for APM and hdparm. ubuntu-laptop-mode only has support for hdparm.